# Sintaxe de seletor css para eliminar elemento <td> com jQuery

Tags: jquery, seletores

Alguma forma de utilizar jquery e seletores de uma forma parecida com esta?

```
$("#tabela td").empty();
```

Necessito eliminar somente as linhas `tr` que contenham `td` de uma tabela como esta, mas não as linhas `tr` que possuem elementos `th`.

Da forma que estou fazendo, elimina as `td`, mas não as `tr` que contém `td`.

```
<table id = "tabela">
    <tr>
        <th>title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro fazer como começou e adicionar `.closest('tr')` assim ele sobe ao elemento `tr` e pode removê-lo.

```
$("#tabela td").closest('tr').empty(); // ou .remove();
```

exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/47T9T/

Comment: Ficou certinho, remove somente as `tr`'s com `td`'s desta forma.

Answer (score 0):

Não havia usado assim antes, mas acredito não tenha problema em continuar utilizando. No meu caso, costumo usar o closest (http://api.jquery.com/closest/) e o remove (http://api.jquery.com/remove/), passando o elemento que recebeu o clique.

Por exemplo:

`<!-- tabela -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Asdf</td>
        <td><a onclick="excluir(this)">Excluir</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>`

`<!-- script -->
// Irá encontrar a primeira ocorrência TR a partir do elemento (no caso, o link) e fazer a ação que mandarmos (no caso, excluir a tr toda).
function excluir(element){
    $(element).closest('tr').remove();
}`

Comment: Oi, atualizei a pergunta, se quiser atualizar a sua resposta..

Comment: Você pode utilizar a mesma ideia, alterando apenas o que quer de fato excluir. Mas acho que no seu caso a opção do Tiago César Oliveira acima é uma boa.

Answer (score 0):

Seu seletor está quase correto.

Para a marcação HTML abaixo

```
<table id="tabela">
    <tr>
        <th>Linha com TH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Linha com TD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Este código JS resolve o problema

```
$("#tabela td").closest("tr").remove();
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Npx67/1/

**Edit1** para atendimento ao requisito